# MS-Access Between Dates Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have a query that is working fine with the exception of not calculating between certain dates.  My initial Query SQL is

```
SELECT 
Roster.UserID, 
SchedulingLog.Category, 
Sum(IIf([CatDetail] Like '*Gain*',[Value],0)) AS Gain,
Sum(IIf([CatDetail] Like '*Used*',[Value],0))+Sum(IIf([CatDetail] Like 'Adj*',[Value],0)) AS Used,
[Gain]+[Used] AS [Left]
FROM SchedulingLog INNER JOIN Roster ON SchedulingLog.UserID = Roster.UserID
WHERE (((SchedulingLog.EventDate)>DateSerial(Year(Date()),5,20)))
GROUP BY Roster.UserID, SchedulingLog.Category
HAVING (((SchedulingLog.Category) Like "DH*" Or (SchedulingLog.Category) Like "Comp*"));
```

This SQL works fine until the new year.  I have modified my code in the `WHERE` statement to use a `BETWEEN` qualifier, but I can not get it to work.  Here is the new SQL...

```
SELECT
Roster.UserID,
SchedulingLog.Category,
Sum(IIf([CatDetail] Like '*Gain*',[Value],0)) AS Gain,
Sum(IIf([CatDetail] Like '*Used*',[Value],0))+Sum(IIf([CatDetail] Like 'Adj*',[Value],0)) AS Used, 
[Gain]+[Used] AS [Left]
FROM SchedulingLog INNER JOIN Roster ON SchedulingLog.UserID = Roster.UserID
WHERE (((SchedulingLog.EventDate) Between DateSerial(Year(Date()-1),5,20) And DateSerial(Year(Date()),5,20)))
GROUP BY Roster.UserID, SchedulingLog.Category
HAVING (((SchedulingLog.Category) Like "DH*" Or (SchedulingLog.Category) Like "Comp*"));
```

The intent of the new SQL is to gather the information between last year 5-20-2012 and this year 5-20-2013.  Where am I missing the boat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

```
DateSerial(Year(Date()-1),5,20)
```

It should be:

```
DateSerial(Year(Date())-1,5,20)
```

Just output both statements in the Immediate Window to see the difference.

Your code (`Year(Date()-1)`) subtracts 1 from today's date (3th January 2013 - 1 = 2th January 2013!!) and takes the year from that (2013), so the result is 20th May **2013**.
So you are effectively loading the data from 20th May 2013 to 20th May 2013!

My code (`Year(Date())-1`) gets the year of today's date (2013) and subtracts 1 from it (--> 2012), so the result is 20th May **2012**.